# LaTeX is mishandling TikZ characters in Venn diagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf, venn-diagrams

I am running TikZ (pgf_210.tds), TeX 3.141592, and Fedora 14.
I am working on Venn diagrams. The examples all do the right art work, but draw the set identification as in

```
\draw \firstcircle node[text=white, below] {$A$}
\draw \secondcircle note[text=white, above] {$B$}
```

on top of each other just left of the midpoint of the left arc of
the intersection.

Any thoughts?

---

```
\begin{document}
%% From a tikz Venn example
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[fill=gray]
\begin{scope}
\clip (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2)
   (1,0) circle(1);  
\fill (0,0) circle (1);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}
\clip (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2)
   (0,0) circle(1);
\fill (1,0) circle(1);
\end{scope}

draw (0,0) circle (1) (0,1) node [text=black,above] at (2,2) {$A$}
    (1,0) circle (1) (1,1) node [text=black,above] at (1,1) {$B$}
    (-2,-2) rectangle (3,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: This is most probably taken from http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/venn-diagram/

Comment: Still no change. I suspect a compatibility problem, either my TeX/LaTeX package
(version 3.14159) or (less likely) Fedora 14. I'll try getting a newer
LaTeX version. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: @JohnSlimick The key here is the version of your _packages_, not of TeX itself. Add `\listfiles` to your source and edit the resulting `**File List**` from the `.log` file into your answer.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question, you are not able to place the labels for the sets at the appropriate points.  The easiest fix for this is to use the syntax `node [<options>] {<node_text>}`. It will automatically be placed relative to the last point in the path:

```
\draw 
    (0,0) circle (1) (0,1) node [text=black,above] {$A$}
    (1,0) circle (1) (1,1) node [text=black,above] {$B$}
    (-2,-2) rectangle (3,3);
```

which produces:

[image]

### Note:

- I have used three separate `\draw` commands as I think that is clearer, but the above syntax also works.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[fill=gray]
\begin{scope}
    \clip (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2) (1,0) circle(1);  
    \fill (0,0) circle (1);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}
    \clip (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2) (0,0) circle(1);
    \fill (1,0) circle(1);
\end{scope}

\draw (0,0) circle (1) (0,1) node [text=black,above] {$A$};
\draw (1,0) circle (1) (1,1) node [text=black,above] {$B$};
\draw (-2,-2) rectangle (3,3);;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```